# EditingControlDataGridView property is null

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

With relation to my previous question mentioned here:
[Custom DataGridViewColumn value disappears after loosing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053869/custom-datagridviewcolumn-value-disappears-after-loosing-focus)

I tried to change my EditControl class. I added an override to the 'OnTextChanged' method. When I run and debug my application, I came to know that the 'EditingControlDataGridView' property for the custom control is not being set. Even though in the designer code I am adding the column into the MetroGrid.

What can the issue be?

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the `OnTextChanged` and examine the call stack. It might be called from some code outside the grid view infrastructure. Also you may add a null check for `EditingControlDataGridView` property and do nothing (don't set `valueChanged`, don't call `NotifyCurrentCellDirty`).

Comment: I fixed it, just put in a condition if datagrid wasn't null then execute the code.